# Is there a better way to Optimize code that takes one value out of a Request body, the data comes in, in json format

Tags: java, json-deserialization, netflix-zuul

I have an request object, that contains a huge amount of data. But there is a filter in my code, where I need to take out just one  element. At the moment I am Deserializing the whole object, which seems overkill to just get one element

This is part of a zuul filter

```
import com.netflix.zuul.context.RequestContext;
```

```
       RequestContext ct = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
       HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       ServletInputStream stream = null;
       try {
            stream = request.getInputStream();
            GetPageRequest page = mapper.readValue(stream,GetPageRequest.class);
            log.info("URL IN BODY "+page.getUrl());
```

It seems over kill to deserialize an entire object to get one element but I cant think of a more efficient and optomized way

Comment: You may read the stream directly as String and look in it what matches your key/value and get it. I think this will avoid parsing and type checking elements into DTO so it will increase performance a little bit.

Comment: https://github.com/jsurfer/JsonSurfer and similar projects might be interesting for your use case

Comment: Thank you, that is def a good idea. Its less process intense than deserialization. Which is  what I am trying to get away from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At it's simplest the request payload can just be a string so you could read the input as a string and then parse what you want out using a regular expression or an `indexOf` or whatever suits best?

Comment: Thank you, that is def a good idea. Its less process intense than deserialization. Which is what I am trying to get away from

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to everyone. I created this method. Streamed inputstream into a string Created a JSONObject which takes in and tokenizies the string

```
 private String getURLFromRequest(ServletInputStream stream) throws IOException, JSONException {
        String requestStr = IOUtils.toString(stream, "UTF-8");
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(requestStr);
        return (String) jsonObj.get("url");
    }
```

Comment: So converting to a ``JSONObject`` is also essentially 'deserializing' the object which you said you wanted to get away from? It may or may not be quicker that ``ObjectMapping``, but essentially it is the same thing.